# Я не могу попасть в админку битрикс

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

Кто-то сменил в dbconn false на true и теперь вместо админки на всю страницу висит ошибка (Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/c/cm48000/public_html/bitrix/modules/main/classes//database.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php72/share/pear') in /home/c/cm48000/public_html/bitrix/modules/main/start.php on line 213)

У меня нет пароля от сервака, что можно предпринять в такой ситуации?

Comment: Если вам мистическим образом повезло, и в корне сайта есть файл `restore.php`, можете попробовать восстановить через него ([дока](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=35&LESSON_ID=6979)). Если же нет и сайт на хостинге -- ищите доступы и пробуйте через файловый менеджер хостинга. Если это именно сервер -- ищите доступы от него. Других вариантов не вижу, если админка не доступна

Comment: Еще вопрос, у чего именно сменили значение?